# How can I hide indent guides in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

How can I hide the vertical dotted indentation lines in Visual Studio 2019?

I tried checking the options available in Edit -> advanced tab and the view menu items but couldn't find it there.

PS: This feature helps me to better focus on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on tools -> Options -> Text editor -> Under Display heading -> Deselect "Show structure guidelines" option. Voila!